# Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call in Oracle Weblogic12c

Tags: java, gwt, server, weblogic12c, managed

I see below error logs in managed `server1` of Oracle WebLogic. While managed `server2` does not have any error. Tried increasing WebLogic memory allocation but didn't help. When does this error come and how to resolve it?

```
 ####<Dec 20, 2019, 9:34:45,440 AM UTC> <Error> <ServletContext-/fierce> 
<ip-XXX> <XXX_mserver1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 
'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <c5b3824c-d0c5- 
4bcb-a246-9eb864e8b2f7-00001333> <1576834485440> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 
0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000000> <Exception 
while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletConfig has not been initialized
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletName(GenericServlet.java:331)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.log(GenericServlet.java:275)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.loadSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.doGetSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.getSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.prepareToRead(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:454)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
    at com.XXX.ui.common.server.service.SpringControllerGWT.processCall(SpringControllerGWT.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at com.ui.common.server.service.SpringControllerGWT.handleRequest(SpringControllerGWT.java:51)
    at com.ui.common.server.service.SpringControllerGWT.handleRequest(SpringControllerGWT.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete tack trace from the server log ?

Comment: logs have been updated. Please check @EmmanuelCollin